# Get multiple values in to a variable and looping through that values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to put multiple values into a variable and looping through that values and I tried the below approach:

```
Table:Dept
    Deptid DeptName
    10      IT
    20      Admin
Declaring a table variable:
    DECLARE @LOOP INT
    DECLARE @COUNTOFRECORDS INT
    DECLARE @x TABLE(
    r_no int not null primary key identity(1,1)
    dept_name VARCHAR(20))

    Insert into @x select deptname from dept
    
    SELECT @LOOP = 1
    SELECT @COUNTOFRECORDS = COUNT(r_no) from @x
    while(@LOOP <= @COUNTOFRECORDS)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @x.dept_name from @x
    END
```

Comment: Use a table variable and treat like INSERT INTO.

Comment: A **scalar** variable will store only one "thing". Either use a table variable as suggested or use the technique from one of your previous questions where you aggregate multiple values into a single string. But perhaps you have prematurely chosen a path? You generally don't want to tightly couple a resultset with "display" and follow it with "loop through that values". Tsql does not display anything - that is a function of the tool used to consume your resultset.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The fact that you precede your SQL with the statement *"Declaring a table variable:"* implies you *think* you are creating a table variable; you aren't. the `TYPE` of a table variable is `table`, `varchar` is a scalar data type.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about looping, you could look into a cursor, but I'm not a fan of cursors (even fast-forward cursors). This approach is pretty straight-forward for looping over each row in your @x table variable:

```
DECLARE @r_no int;
-- Set variable to the smallest r_no:
SET @r_no = (select min(r_no) from @x);
WHILE @r_no is not null
BEGIN

   -- Do what you need with the single row:
   SELECT @x.dept_name FROM @x WHERE r_no = @r_no;

   --Increment the loop (find the next-largest r_no):
   SET @r_no = (select min(r_no) from @x where r_no > @r_no);

END
```

As long as you use `SET @r_no = (select` instead of `SELECT @r_no = min` to increment the counter, then your loop will exit automatically after the last row.